# combination of buttons in event OnKeydown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, key, keydown

I need to set up combination of buttons in input form of my react app.

1. "CTRL + "ArrowUp"
2. "ArrowUp"

**My code is something like this.**

```
//Form

<input onKeyDown={keyHandler}/>

//handler

const keyhandler = (e) => {

if(e.key === "ArrowUp") {//do something}

if(e.key === 'ArrowUp' && e.getModifierState("Control")) {//do another thing}
```

The problem is when event fired with combination, first 'if' also true. How separate "ArrowUp" and "ArrowUp" with ctrl button?

**I also try like this (but it didn't help):**

```
if(e.key === 'ArrowUp' && event.ctrlKey){ //do another thing}
```

Comment: Did you try to change the sequence of your `if`-statements? Just check for `ctrl` button first. That means: move the second `if`-statement in front of the first one!

Answer (score 0):

Just following your logic,

```
  if (Control is pressed) {
    if (ArrowUp is pressed) {
        // both are pressed
    }
  } else {
    if (ArrowUp is pressed) {
        // only arrow up is pressed
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem by using this one.

```
if(!e.getModifierState('Control')){
 if(e.key == 'ArrowUp'){ 
  //single button action
  }
}
if(e.key == "ArrowUp" && e.getModifierState("Control")){
 //combo buttons action
}
```